# Postfix block double extensions in archive attachment

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis, attachment

These days I have problems with trojans in attachments like:

> 1. //EZuS.zip//invoice_scan_xcFSuO.xls.js contains a potentially infected object HEUR:Trojan-Downloader.Script.Generic.
> 2. //TuxX.zip//invoice_YAFFOg.doc.js contains a potentially infected object HEUR:Trojan-Downloader.Script.Generic.

I have a relay to my in-house server. Relay with postfix + amavis + spam assassin + clamav.

We need to send and receive .js files. So i only want to block the .doc*.js and .xls*.js

Which is the most efficient way to block this kind of spam?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you with your question.

Answer (score 4):

**Postfix Header Checks**

Blocking double extensions can be done with regex.  Here is an example of how to block any extension.

**Create** `/etc/postfix/header_checks` and maybe block some of these extensions

Modify as required:  Here are 2 ways to do the same thing you asked for.

```
# do something with JS files
#
# method 1, much like what you asked for
/^(.*)name=\"(.*)\.[0-z]{3,}\.js\"$/ REJECT BAD_ATTACHMENT_3CHAR

# method 2, specific on extensions before the .js, customize as desired
/^(.*)name=\"(.*)\.(exe|lnk|dll|shs|vbe|hta|mht|com|vbs|vbe|js|jse|bat|cmd|vxd|scr|shm|pif|chm|pdf|zip|dmg)\.js\"$/ REJECT BAD_ATTACHMENT_PLUSJS

# log attachments
/^Content-(Type|Disposition):.*(file)?name=/    WARN ATTACHMENT
/^(.*)name=\"(.*)\./                            WARN ATTACHMENT
```

**Configure** postfix to use this:

```
postconf -e "header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks"
postfix reload
```

**Do this on a test system first and keep an eye on syslog.**

Comment: Hi, both works for attachments like *.js and blocks the double extension like defined. If the files is within a zip or tar it won't work.

Comment: You can customize that line to exclude any extensions you wish to allow through.  That was just an example.

Comment: I have a "SPAM.zip" within this zip file is a file spam.doc.js. The Postfix header_checks test the name of the zip file and not the file within the zip. Only the extensions of the attachment get blocked not the files within, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Correct, this method only looks at filenames.  The answer was based on your original question.  To look inside the file will require something external to Postfix, such as the method you are already using with amavis+clamav.